# Sort an array based on a tuple of 4 indices in C

Tags: c, sorting

I have an interesting problem, which I have been struggling with for the past 2 days without a concrete solution.
I am attempting to write a program in C which takes the following input array:

```
               1,1,5,5,
               1,1,5,9,
               2,2,6,2,
               1,2,5,5,
               1,3,6,6,
               1,4,5,1,
               4,1,5,6,
               5,2,7,1,
               1,1,6,0,
               2,2,5,0,
```

step1: group the above array based on the 3rd column like this (bucket sort on tuple of 4 elements (i.e. each row), based on values of 3rd column:

```
               2,2,5,5
               1,1,5,9,
               1,2,5,5,
               1,4,5,1,
               4,1,5,6,
               2,2,5,0,
               2,2,6,2,
               1,3,6,6,
               1,1,6,0,
               5,2,7,1
```

Step 2: Finally sort the elements based on the 4th column within each bucket like this:

Final Output Array:

```
              2,2,5,0,
              1,4,5,1,
              2,2,5,5,
              1,2,5,5,
              4,1,5,6,
              1,1,5,9,
              1,1,6,0,
              2,2,6,2,
              1,3,6,6,
              5,2,7,1
```

The elements in the 1st and 2nd column do not play any role in the above sorting process.

I have tried various techniques, using quicksort or bucket sort followed by a subsequent quicksort. Nothing has worked out quite right.
Could anyone suggest a method of doing this in C, using appropriate data structures.

Comment: How is this different than sorting on a virtual key of a 3rd-column and 4th column composed entity? This hardly seems like it should take days to consider, unless I'm completely missing something (which wouldn't be the first time). A properly written `qsort()` comparator and an entity-width of four "values" (you never specified whether they're `int`, `unsigned int`, `short`, etc.) would/should make short work of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *x, const void *y){
    int (*a)[4] = (int(*)[4])x;
    int (*b)[4] = (int(*)[4])y;
    if((*a)[2]==(*b)[2])
        return (*a)[3] - (*b)[3];
    else
        return (*a)[2] - (*b)[2];
}

int main(void){
    int data[][4] = {
        {1,1,5,5},
        {1,1,5,9},
        {2,2,6,2},
        {1,2,5,5},
        {1,3,6,6},
        {1,4,5,1},
        {4,1,5,6},
        {5,2,7,1},
        {1,1,6,0},
        {2,2,5,0}
    };
    int size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
    int i,j;
    qsort(data, size, sizeof(data[0]), cmp);
    //result print
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        for(j=0;j<4;++j)
            printf("%d ", data[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Didnt know it could be done so simply.

Answer (score 5):

The thing is, you don't really need to do multiple sorts; you can do a *single* sort based on two fields of your tuple.

Just use an existing sort algorithm, but with a comparing function which looks like this:

```
if (val[2] != otherval[2])
    return val[2] < otherval[2];
else
    return val[3] < otherval[3];
```

This will use the third column to sort, unless the values are equal, in which case it will use the fourth.

Or if you want to do two separate sorts, FIRST sort by the fourth column, THEN by the third.

Answer (score 2):

This should actually be pretty simple to do. The standard qsort function takes a call back which compares two elements. Just write your callback to expect the elements to be the subarrays and compare first using the Third element. If the third elements are equal then compare using the fourth element.

Comment: +1 completely concur (as if that wasn't obvious from my prior comment). Stressing the strict weak order of the composite 3rd and 4th column value is important, but it looks like your updating to reflect that.

Comment: Dictated this answer using Siri. Required several little edits!

Comment: Wrong. When encoutering a tie, the compare function should not compare the 4th rlrment, but the absolute pointer value. (see the intended output by the OP)

Comment: @wildplasser Huh? The specification pretty clearly mentions the fourth column in step two; nothing about Absolute pointer values.

Comment: I rest my case. (I thought it was about conservative sort, but that will be next monday, I presume)

Comment: I have no idea what we're talking about.